# how can I fixed Oracle Client Setup problems?

Tags: java, oracle, client

I want to setup `oracle client` in my server . But I see this `error`. How can I fixed?

The `Java RunTİme Enviroment` was not found at `bin\javaw.exe`. Hence, the `Oracle Universal Installer` cannot be run. Please visit this [link](http://www.javasoft.com) and install `JRE version 1.3.1 or higher` and try again.

Comment: Do you have a JRE/JDK installed in your machine? Did you give the correct path while installing oracle client?

Comment: Where is the error? And why do you use so old version of JRE?

Comment: Which OS is this? Windows?

Comment: If you have the JDK installed you can specify the path `setup.exe -jreLoc C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`

Comment: @Hirak I install jre7 and jre8 path is C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin and I install jdk is path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05  and I setup.exe(oracle) is my desktop

Comment: @AlexR windows server 2007

Comment: @KennethClark how can I this?

Comment: Run the Setup from command line (Open Command Prompt) make sure the current folder is your desktop and run the command line `setup.exe -jreLoc "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05"`

Comment: @KennethClark setup.exe is not recongnized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is that setup of JRE does not create environment variable `JAVA_HOME` required by many tools probably including Oracle client. So, just add this variable manually. It should point to path where your JRE is installed, i.e. in your case `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\`

Comment: Variable name : PATH and variable value : C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin is this true? I did this. But same problem

Comment: I add environment variable JAVA_HOME and C:\Program Files\Java\jre8 but same problem

Answer (score 1):

from: http://paulsoftech.blogspot.de/2012/09/binjavawexe-not-found-when-trying-to.html

> 1. install JRE-1.7.0
> 2. add these 2 lines at the file oraparam.ini
>
>    JRE_VERSION=1.7.0
>
>    JRE_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
> 3. comments the line :
>
>    JRE_VERSION=1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by some issue with the unzipped installer.  I copied the zip to my local machine, unzipped and installed without issue.